# Brew pkg-config on Mavericks

Tags: homebrew

I have updated my OSX from Lion to Mavericks.

When I run brew doctor I am getting this error:

```
Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this directory from your path, if you want the warning to go away.  Alternatively, uninstall whatever is installed in that directory.